# SweetAlert2, loading alert for Angular RxJs request

Tags: angular, rxjs, sweetalert2

I am using `SweetAlert2` and `Angular 2+` to display a loading alert while my queries are loading.

I am looking for an elegant way to achieve this.

For now, here is my solution, that I think could be simplified:

```
public async displayLoadingModal(obs: Observable<any>, message: string) {
obs.subscribe( () => 
  Swal.close(),
  err => Swal.close()
);

     return Swal.fire({
      title: 'Please wait',
      text: message,
      onOpen: () => {
      Swal.showLoading();
    },
  });
}



let obj: Observable<any> = this.myService.getWhatever(id)
this.modalService.displayLoadingModal(obj, 'Updating whatever');

obj.subscribe(
     response => this.handleSuccess(processType),
     error => this.handleError(error, processType),
);
```

Then the loading alert will close automatically.